# input hidden don't run onChange event

Tags: javascript, html, input, hidden, onchange

I have the follow code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function doReload()
{
    alert('');
    document.getElementById('doPostBack').value = "0";      
    location.href = 'users.php';
}

function changes()
{
document.getElementById('doPostBack').value = '1';  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="users" style="height: 80%;">
<form id="submitForm" name="submitForm" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Novo Usuário" title="Adiciona um novo Usuario"      onclick="location.href = 'registerUser.php'" />
<input type="button" value="teste" onclick="changes()">
```

When I click on teste, the function doesn't execute.

Comment: I don't see element with ID `doPostBack` are it somewhere else?

Comment: Function is executing, but it didnt find specified element. One run with enabled js debugging and you would see it. Also I didnt see any hidden inputs :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get an *onchange* listener to fire, you can't do it by programatically changing the value. [Onchange events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) are dispatched when a control's value has changed **and it loses focus**. It is intended to be in response to a user action, not a programatic action.

You can instead call the onchange function straight after changing the value, or dispatch an onchange event to an appropriate location in the document.